# How to access files in another drive using php?

Tags: php, windows, apache, lan

I'm building a webpage for a local network in windows . Images in my webpage are stored in E drive while htdocs is in C drive , I want to access images in the E drive and show(link) them in the webpage. like this

```
http://192.168.1.5/e://LAN/image.jpg
```

When I tried above link it gave me 403. 
I tried adding below two codes seperately to httpd.conf like most answers suggested. But did't work .

```
<Directory "e://LAN/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
```

```
<Directory />
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

any answer would be appreciated ,

Comment: Are you sure it should be two slashes? Shouldn't it be `e:/LAN/`?

Comment: @klutt two slashes works too , but I have the problem with permissions . I can move the file to e://LAN using php without a problem , but I can not access the file from browser .

Answer (score 1):

Use full Windows path to the file it should be working: **"E:\folder\image.jpg"**

or just copy the file in the **htdocs/project** directory for testing purpose.

Comment: I used full windows path like below , using a computer in LAN , But I can't access it , http://192.168.1.5/e://LAN/image.jpg,  copying one file to htdocs works but there are like 100 000 photos , So it is difficult to copy .

Answer (score 0):

Open the Apache config file: httpd.conf
Start by creating a directory with the path to the images (back slashes). Add Require all granted to that directory statement.
Then create an 'alias' in the httpd.conf file with full path to those images including the Drive letter (forward slashes here).
Restart Apache. Then create a PHP variable that mirrors that directory path and Apache will parse the images in that folder using the 'alias;.